# My Celery task is not running

Tags: django, celery, cron

Here is my tasks.py file:

```
from celery.schedules impor

@task(name='coupon.generate_reports')
def update_monthly_coupons_reports():
    # some code


app.conf.beat_schedule = {
    # Executes every Monday morning at 7:30 a.m.
    'add-every-morning': {
        'task': 'coupon.generate_reports',
        'schedule': crontab(hour=7, minute=30),
    },
}
```

and `CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULER = 'djcelery.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler'` is in settings.

But there is no result of task exectuting. Is there steps that I've missed?

Comment: How did you start Celery?

Comment: How is this running?  There are syntax errors in your tasks.py file.

Comment: my crontab setting is not working either, I cannot figure out why, you can try `'schedule': timedelta(minutes=10),`